# Catch a key press using accelerator tables without preventing typing in text controls

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to use an accelerator table to catch a key press globally in the window so that I can fire a method in response. However, the accelerator table seems to destroy the event that would otherwise be created by pressing the key, preventing me from typing it into text controls. Is there any way to get around this behavior, or some other solution to my problem?

Edit: Here's a better example of the kind of situation:

```
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(-1,-1))
        ...
            randomId = wx.NewId()
        parent.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onKey, id=randomId)
        accTable = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_NORMAL, 96, randomId)]) # 96 is the keycode for `
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accTable)
        ...

class ctrlpanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        ...
            grid = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=7, vgap=7)

        self.lblfreq = wx.StaticText(self, label="Base Frequency (hz): ")
        grid.Add(self.lblfreq, pos=(0,0))
        self.freq = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="0", size=(100, 20))
        grid.Add(self.freq, pos=(0,1))

            self.waveList = ['Sine', 'Semicircle', 'Saw', 'Square']
        self.lblwave = wx.StaticText(self, label="Wave Shape: ")
        grid.Add(self.lblwave, pos=(1,0))
        self.wave = wx.Choice(self, choices=self.waveList)
        self.wave.SetStringSelection('Sine')
        grid.Add(self.wave, pos=(1,1))

        self.SetSizerAndFit(grid)
```

With this code, the accelerator table works perfectly, picking up my key presses wherever the focus is on the window, and activating the onKey method. However, when the focus is on the text control, I can't type the character I'm picking up into the text control because the accelerator table is handling it the event before it goes anywhere else, or preventing the normal event from being fired or propagated. I want to be able to make the event still happen normally, so text will appear in the text control when typed, even if those keys are set to do some other action generally in the window. Is there any event.Skip() type thing I could use here?

Comment: Can you provide a small code sample which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the issue is without more information, like OS, wx version or a small example that shows the problem. However, here are a couple example articles on the subject that might help you figure out the problem:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/07/02/wxpython-working-with-menus-toolbars-and-accelerators/

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/02/wxpython-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerators/

Comment: I have already looked at these pages. They helped me figure out how to use the accelerator table, but they have no information on my current problem, which is allowing the key events to be handled normally by my controls after the accelerator table is done with them.

Comment: You may need to call event.Skip() at the end of the handler

Comment: It doesn't work because the event passed to the handler is not the KeyEvent that would normally be created but a MenuEvent, as specified. Furthermore, the original KeyEvent would be bound to the TextCtrl itself, would it not? I don't know any way to access the original KeyEvent, or if it even exists anywhere. That's the problem.